# How can I compare entries in linked lists?

Tags: c, file, linked-list, stack, project

I am doing a C project that manages the number of rooms in a building, where I can either choose to reserve or pre-reserve a room. For that, I will ask the user to input some data (name, the ammount of time he wants to reserve the room and the room he wants to reserve).

I've been able to do it already. However, I also need to be able to give the option for the user to pre-reserve a room when it's already reserved, so if the reserve is cancelled, the first user to pre-reserve for the same time will be assigned to the room.

What do I mean by "pre-reserve":  Put the user in a waiting list that follows the FIFO (First in, first out) philosophy

Can you suggest a way to do it?

This is my header file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <time.h>

#define ARQ "Dados.txt" /*ARQUIVO COM OS DADOS*/

#define OP_INSERIR     '1'
#define OP_ALTERAR     '2'
#define OP_APAGAR      '3'
#define OP_LISTAR      '4'
#define OP_PESQUISAR   '5'
#define OP_PRERESERVAR '6'

#define OP_SAIR       '0'

#define OP_PESQ_HORAS '1'
#define OP_PESQ_NOME  '2'

char *MainMenu[]={
    "\n\tM E N U    P R I N C I P A L\n",
    "1. Fazer Reserva",
    "2. Alterar Reserva",
    "3. Apagar Reserva",
    "4. Listar Reservas",
    "5. Pesquisar",
    "0. Sair",
    NULL
};

char *PesqMenu[]={
    "1. Pesquisar por Intervalo de Tempo",
    "2. Pesquisar por Nome",
    "0. Voltar",
    NULL
};

FILE *fp;

typedef struct{
    char Nome[100];
    int Sala;
    int Hora_inicio;
    int Minuto_inicio;
    int Hora_fim;
    int Minuto_fim;
    char Status; /* '*' Indica que o registo está apagado */
} PESSOA;
```

The rest of the program (I've not been able to split it in .c files, has my compiler loops into the question: "It seems that this project has not been build yet. Do you want to build it?" If you can also help me in this matter, I would appreciate) :

```
#include "header.h"

void Mensagem(char *msg);

/*Lê os dados de um registo introduzidos pelo utilizador*/

void Ler_Pessoa(PESSOA *p){

    printf("Introduza o seu Nome (Primeiro e Ultimo) : "); gets(p->Nome);
    printf("Introduza o numero da sala que quer reservar:  "); scanf("%d", &p->Sala);
    printf("Introduza a partir de que horas quer reservar a sala (HH:MM): "); scanf("%2d:%2d",&p->Hora_inicio , &p->Minuto_inicio);
    printf("Introduza ate que horas quer reservar a sala (HH:MM): "); scanf("%2d:%2d", &p->Hora_fim , &p->Minuto_fim);
    p -> Status = ' ';
    fflush(stdin);
    system("cls");
}

void Mostrar_Pessoa(PESSOA p){
    printf("Nome          : %s\n",p.Nome);
    printf("Sala Reservada: %d\n",p.Sala);
    printf("Hora Inicial  : %2d:%2d",p.Hora_inicio , p.Minuto_inicio);
    printf("\tHora Final    : %2d:%2d\n",p.Hora_fim , p.Minuto_fim);
}

/*Adicionar uma Pessoa ao Arquivo */

void Adicionar_Pessoa(PESSOA p){
    fseek(fp , 0L , SEEK_END);
    if (fwrite(&p, sizeof(p), 1, fp)!=1)
        Mensagem("Adicionar Pessoa: Falhou a escrita  do Registo");
}

/* Coloca uma mensagem na tela */

void Mensagem(char *msg){
    printf(msg);
    getchar();
}
/*
 * Verifica se o Arquivo já existe. Se não existir, ele é criado.
 * Se já existir, abre-o em Modo de Leitura e Escrita (r+b)
 */

 void Inic(){
     fp = fopen(ARQ, "r+b"); /* Tenta Abrir*/
     if (fp==NULL){
         fp=fopen(ARQ, "w+b"); /*Cria o Arquivo*/
         if (fp==NULL){
             fprintf(stderr, "ERRO FATAL: Impossivel Criar Arquivo de Dados \n");
             exit(1);
         }
     }
 }

/*
 * Faz um Menu Simples com as opções do vector de Strings.
 * Seleciona a Opção, usando o primeiro caracter de cada string.
 * Devolve o primeiro caracter da opção
 */

 char Menu(char *Opcoes[]){
     int i;
     char ch;
     while(1){
         printf("\n");
         for (i=0 ; Opcoes[i] != NULL ; i++){
             printf("\n\t\t%s\n\n", Opcoes[i]);
         }
         printf("\n\n\t\tOpcao : ");
         ch = getchar(); fflush(stdin);
         system("cls");
         for (i=0 ; Opcoes[i]!=NULL ; i++){
             if (Opcoes[i][0]==ch)
                return ch;
         }
     }
 }

void Inserir_Pessoa(){
    PESSOA x;
    Ler_Pessoa(&x);
    Adicionar_Pessoa(x);
}

void Alterar_Pessoa(){
    PESSOA x;
    long int n_reg;
    char resp;
    printf("Qual o No. do Registo: ");
    scanf("%ld",&n_reg);
    fflush(stdin);
    if (fseek(fp, (n_reg-1)*sizeof(PESSOA),SEEK_SET)!=0){
        Mensagem("Registo Inexistente!!!");
        return;
    }
    if (fread(&x, sizeof(PESSOA),1,fp)!=1){
        Mensagem("Problemas na Leitura do Registo!!!");
        return;
    }
    if (x.Status == '*'){
        Mensagem("Um Registo Apagado nao pode ser alterado!!!\n\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n\nDados Actuais\n\n");
    Mostrar_Pessoa(x);
    printf("\n\nDeseja alterar a sua reserva? (s/n): "); resp = getchar();
    if(toupper (resp)!= 'S')
        return;
    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n\nNovos Dados\n\n");
    Ler_Pessoa(&x);

    // Recuar um Registo no Arquivo//
    fseek(fp, -(long) sizeof(PESSOA), SEEK_CUR);
    // Reescrever o Registo;
    fwrite(&x, sizeof(PESSOA), 1, fp);
    fflush(fp); /*Despejar os dados no Disco*/
}

void Apagar_Pessoa(){
    PESSOA x;
    long int n_reg;
    char resp;

    printf("Qual o No. do Registo: ");
    scanf("%ld",&n_reg); fflush(stdin);
    if (fseek(fp,(n_reg-1)*sizeof(PESSOA),SEEK_SET)!=0){
        Mensagem ("Registo Inexistente!!!");
        return;
    }
    if (fread (&x, sizeof(PESSOA), 1 ,fp)!=1){
        Mensagem("Problemas na Leitura do Registo!!!");
        return;
    }
    if (x.Status=='*'){
        Mensagem("O Registo ja esta Apagado!!!\n\n");
        return;
    }
    printf("\n\nDados Actuais\n\n");
    Mostrar_Pessoa(x);
    printf("\n\nApagar o Registo (s/n)?: "); resp=getchar();
    fflush(stdin);
    if(toupper (resp)!= 'S')
        return;
    x.Status='*';

    fseek (fp, -(long) sizeof(PESSOA) , SEEK_CUR);
    fwrite(&x, sizeof(PESSOA), 1, fp);
    fflush(fp); /*Despejar os dados para o Disco*/
    system("cls");
}

void Listar_Pessoa(){
    long int N_Linhas = 0;
    PESSOA reg;
    rewind(fp);
    while(1){
        if (fread(&reg, sizeof(reg), 1 ,fp )!= 1) break; /*Sair do Ciclo*/
        if (reg.Status == '*') continue ; /*Passa ao próximo*/
        Mostrar_Pessoa(reg);
        N_Linhas++;
        if (N_Linhas %20==0)
            Mensagem("PRESSIONE <ENTER> para continuar . . .");
    }
    Mensagem("\n\nPRESSIONE <ENTER> para continuar . . ."); /*No fim da Listagem*/
}

void Pesquisar_HORAS(int ini, int fim){
    PESSOA reg;
    rewind (fp);

    while (fread(&reg, sizeof(PESSOA), 1, fp)){
        if (reg.Status != '*' && reg.Hora_inicio>=ini && reg.Hora_inicio <=fim)
            Mostrar_Pessoa(reg);
    }
    Mensagem("\n\nPRESSIONE <ENTER> para continuar . . . "); /* No fim da Listagem */
}

void Pesquisar_Nome(char *s){
    PESSOA reg;
    rewind(fp);

    while (fread(&reg , sizeof(PESSOA) , 1 , fp)){
        if (reg.Status!= '*' && strstr(reg.Nome,s))
            Mostrar_Pessoa(reg);
    }
    Mensagem ("\n\nPRESSIONE <ENTER> para continuar . . ."); /*No fim da Listagem*/
}

void main(){
    system("MODE con cols=100 lines=40");
    char Opcao;
    Inic();
    printf("Mini Projecto de Praticas de Programacao Procedimental\n");
    printf("Trabalho por:\n\nJoao Pedro Baptista de Oliveira, n%c 2010129867\nTomas Morgado de Carvalho Conceicao, n%c 2012138578\n\n",248,248);
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    time_t t;
    time(&t);
    printf("Data: %s\n", ctime(&t));
    printf("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n");

    while ((Opcao =Menu(MainMenu))!=OP_SAIR){
        switch(Opcao){
            case OP_INSERIR: Inserir_Pessoa(); break;
            case OP_ALTERAR: Alterar_Pessoa(); break;
            case OP_APAGAR : Apagar_Pessoa(); break;
            case OP_LISTAR : Listar_Pessoa(); break;
            case OP_PESQUISAR:
            while ((Opcao=Menu(PesqMenu))!= OP_SAIR){
                switch (Opcao){
                    case OP_PESQ_HORAS:{
                        int n1,n2;
                        printf("Intervalo de horas: ");
                        scanf("%d",&n1);
                        printf("Ate: ");
                        scanf("%d",&n2);
                        fflush(stdin);
                        Pesquisar_HORAS(n1,n2); break;
                        }
                    case OP_PESQ_NOME:{
                        char string[BUFSIZ +1];
                        printf("Introduza o nome que quer pesquisar: ");
                        gets(string); fflush(stdin);
                        Pesquisar_Nome(string);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n\t\tDepartamento de Engenharia Informatica - Universidade de Coimbra\n\n");
}
```

Comment: You may find it helpful to refer to the action of pre-reserving a room as "putting the user on a wait-list for the room".

Comment: @STLDeveloper Thank you for your suggestion, you're right, it could lead to misunderstandments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how you're storing this information (possibly due to language or storage code not posted), but the title of your question suggests linked lists.

A fairly efficient (both memory and performance wise) solution to this problem is to have a hash table (with buckets) where the key for the hash table is a unique identifier for the room (number/id), and the values stored at each slot in the hash table are the structures of people requesting the room (possibly your `PESSOA` struct).

Then you have 3 main scenarios:
- If hash table entry `i` is empty (no values/buckets), the room is free.
- The first value/bucket of hash table entry `i` is the person currently in the room.
- The remaining values/buckets of hash table entry `i` are the people waiting for the room.

This is efficient because you don't need to store a full list of rooms to assign people to, and finding a particular room is constant time.

When a new person wants to "pre-reserve", you simple get their information, jump to the hash table entry by room id, and append to the value/bucket list.  When a person reliquinshes a room, jump to hash table entry by room id and remove first value/bucket, essentially bumping the very next person up to the first value/bucket.

If you need to find a room based upon person name, you can maintain a second hash table where key is person name and values/buckets are the same struct of information, which should also contain room id as well.  Keys in this hash table do not need to be unique, so long as it also supports buckets for name collisions.